# enter in asp:TextBox clicks my button (which has a js function bound to it)

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

basically I have this:

```
<asp:TextBox runat='server' />
<button id='b2'>hi</button>

<script>
$('#b2').click(function(e){
e.preventDefault();
alert('you clicked the button');

});
</script>
```

**the problem is that when hitting enter inside the textbox the click event on the b2 occurs so I get the js function executed**, anybody knows how to stop this?

Answer (score 0):

Pressing the return/enter key while focusing a text box is treated the same way as clicking on the submit button. What you can do is attach a `keypress` event handler to all text boxes in your form, and simply ignore the return key press.

Code looks like this:

```
$('input[type="text"]').keypress(function(event) {
        if(event.keyCode == 13) {
            event.preventDefault();
            alert("enter!");
        }
    });
```

Note that I don't use ASP, so I tested this with a standard HTML text box and submit button.

Comment: (about the answer that was just deleted) e.target is always HtmlButtonElement, but e.clientX and e.clientY are 0 and 0 when called from hitting enter in textbox... also screenX and screenY and quite a lot of other stuff is 0 (I see this in chrome's firebug), probably I could use that

Answer (score 0):

adding the attribute `type="button"` to the `button` tag stopped this behavior o_O